# How can I create a Stack Exchange account associated with an existing account?

Tags: support, login

I log in to this site with a Google account.

Because Google is blocked in China, I have to use a proxy.

Sometimes I want to login to Stack Overflow from another PC which does not have proxy software. It really make me hurt, so I want to create a native Stack Exchange account.

I went to `Edit Profile & Settings` -> `My Logins` -> `add more logins…`, but no `native Stack Exchange account` was available in there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hm, that appears to be an oversight. In the *Or, you can manually enter your OpenID* box, enter

```
openid.stackexchange.com
```

- [Switch from OpenID to a Stack Exchange login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243361)
- [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234664)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I think `stackexchange account option`  should be added to `add more logins…` page.

Comment: @Mithril me too

Comment: @Mithril you can suggest that in meta stack exchange, maybe with a picture of the issue. I could try, but I think you are in a better position to do it as you know the issue better.

Comment: Creating a new account for each stackexchange* site drives me nuts

Comment: @J. C. Leitão I have post a suggestion at [here]:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268138/add-more-logins-page-need-a-stackexchange-account-option, hope it would be paid attention to.

Comment: @StevenPenny as Anna Lear's indicates in [her new answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol/268141#268141) to my question you linked, this is actually by design and not an oversight,

Comment: @Mithril Wish I didn't have to create a new stack exchange account to upvote your meta.stackexchange post.